# Value cannot be null error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, null

On debugging I get the value I am expected to have,

as

[image]

However when the execution proceeds.I get the following

[image]

Why so ?

Comment: Could you please show your work as a text? Since I'm at work now, I can't see images from imgur..

Comment: Check if ProductVariants is null?

Comment: Put a break point on line 188 and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Thnk you for downvotings :)

Initialisations of the productvariant list was required.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize productDto.ProductVariants before assigning any value.